# How to overlay a div inner elements?

Tags: html, css

Peace and Blessing be upon you.

Basically I have:

```
<div class="container">
  <video class="viddeo"></video>
  <img class="img" src=""/>
</div>
```

Just wanna overlay `img` over `video` element.
FYI: (can't and don't wanna use `position:absolute;`).

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7qhygsoj/

Comment: if you don't want to use absolute, can you use JS? I personally recommend to use absolute though. can you tell me why you can't use absolute?

Comment: @Lucian Because These elements are actually created dynamically with a for loop and if u use `position:absolute` it overlays all other unnecessary  elements too.

Comment: it won't if you make proper layout and create `position: relative` for the parent. make each parent for each element that is created in a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set image `position:relative` and then `top` value same as the `height` of `video` but `negative value` as we need to move `image tag` to `top`, as below,

```css
.container{
  height:200px;
  width:300px;
  background:black;
}
.viddeo{
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
  background:grey;
}
.img{
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
  background:blue;
  position:relative;
  top:-155px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <video class="viddeo"></video>
  <img class="img" src=""/>
</div>
```